# How to add/ remove createElement from DOM in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, dom

In my angular directive, I'm creating an external script from DOM for a particular object in a list, in which it adds 'script' tag and div content. I'm able to add it but I can't remove the scripts. I'm using a button with a list of object, let say button contains list of {a,b,c}. I want to add DOM element for a, remove DOM element for b and add it for c when clicked. My question is how can I create & remove DOM element for appending scripts.

My code for creating element is

```
var a = document.createElement('script');
a.src = 'errors.js' // here 22 &223 are codes extracted from errors.js         
a.setAttribute('source', 22);
a.setAttribute('source', 223);
var e = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
e.parentNode.insertBefore(a,e);
```

This is what I'm using for creating an element. Is there a better way to do in Angular.js? I'm trying to remove the created element and its attributes.

Thanks!

Comment: if u wants to create an elemnt y you are creating using javascript may be you try this                     $scope.div = document.createElement("div");
  angular.element(document.getElementsByTagName('body')).append( $scope.div);

Comment: I want to create script and append it through dom

Comment: $scope.script= document.createElement("script"); angular.element(document.getElementsByTagName('body')).append( $scope.script);

Comment: Adding is okay, i'm struggling with removing the elements. Thanks for the comment though

Answer (score -1):

You can remove angular.element("script").remove() to remove an element based on selector

Same way angular.element("selector").append( "Your script tag" ) to add elemement